# NSXMLParser app terminating "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Tags: ios, xml, parsing, nsxmlparser

Hi guys I'm looking for a way to parse my XML to a few numbers of labels, the "XMLReader" class is where my XML to Dictionary converter is and which works fine for all my other views.
and "getValue" is a method to remove the whitespaces and tabs.
Now when i try to feed my labels with data i get this exception: NSArray unrecognized selector sent to instance:0x....

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSDate* date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"HHddMMyyyy"];
NSString* date_str = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
NSString *requestUrl = [NSString 
stringWithFormat:@"xyz",date_str];
NSURL *staturl= [NSURL URLWithString:requestUrl];
NSURLRequest *statrequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:staturl];
NSURLResponse *statresponse;
NSError *staterror;
NSData * statdata = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:statrequest 
returningResponse:&statresponse error:&staterror];
if (staterror) {
    NSLog(@"URL Error");
}
NSString *statsdataAsString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:statdata 
encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSDictionary *statsdictionary = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:statsdataAsString 
error:&staterror];

_stCreditlabel.text =[XMLReader getValue:[[[[statsdictionary 
objectForKey:@"Statistics"]objectForKey:@"Statistics"]objectForKey:@"Statistic"]objectForKey:@"Name"]];
```

XML:

```
<Statistics xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="xyz">
   <Statistics>
    <Statistic>
     <Name>heute</Name>
    <Statistic>
      <Name></Name>
      <Value></Value>
    </Statistic>
    <Statistic>
     <Name></Name>
     <Value>518</Value>
    </Statistic>
   </Statistic>
  <Statistic>
   <Name>Allgemein</Name>
   <Statistic>
     <Name>Online</Name>
     <Value>2458</Value>
   </Statistic>
   <Statistic>
     <Name>Lager</Name>
     <Value>444</Value>
   </Statistic>     
  </Statistic>
 </Statistics>
</Statistics>
```

Log:

```
2014-04-15 11:04:22.282 MConsole[763:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught 
exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM objectForKey:]: 
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x972ea70'
po 0x972ea70
<__NSArrayM 0x972ea70>(
{
Name =     {
    text = "\n  \n    \n      heute";
};
Statistic =     (
            {
        Name =             {
            text = "\n      \n       ";
        };
        Value =             {
            text = "\n        9";
        };
        text = "\n      ";
    },
            {
        Name =             {
            text = "\n      \n        ";
        };
        Value =             {
            text = "\n        518";
        };
        text = "\n      ";
    }
);
text = "\n    ";
},
{
Name =     {
    text = "\n    \n      Allgemein";
};
Statistic =     (
            {
        Name =             {
            text = "\n      \n        Online";
        };
        Value =             {
            text = "\n        2458";
        };
        text = "\n      ";
    },
            {
        Name =             {
            text = "\n      \n        Lager";
        };
        Value =             {
            text = "\n        444";
        };
        text = "\n      ";
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `NSDictionary *statsdictionary = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:statsdataAsString 
error:&staterror];` is returning an NSArray, and not a NSDictionary, so the NSXMLParser crashes since an NSArray doesn't know any methods named object for key.

EDIT:

In your case, the last two lines needs to be changed to something like this (NB: UNTESTED!):

```
NSArray *statsArray = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:statsdataAsString 
error:&staterror];

_stCreditlabel.text = [[statsArray[0] valueForKey:@"Name"] valueForKey:@"text];
```

If you want to access more of the `statistic` elements inside the `statistics` array, you can loop them with:

```
for (NSDictionary *statsObject in statsArray){

}
```

Also, I'd recommend this tutorial on how to parse Xml in iOS: http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/xml-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml.

Comment: You either need to fix you XMLReader-class so it always returns a dictionary, or change your parser code to loop an array instead of doing lookups in a dictionary. Without having looked at your XMLReader method or the rest of your project, it is hard to tell if one solution is better than the other

Comment: well that is the XMLReader class i use from this site:
http://ios.biomsoft.com/2011/09/11/simple-xml-to-nsdictionary-converter/

Comment: i prefer the 2nd solution, thanks again for your help.

Comment: Updated my answer. The XMLReader you are using have some issues, so I'd highly recommend you to fix it or write your own. The biggest problem is that it doesn't return the object-type the implementation promises it should return. Especially, in `- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement` it adds arrays to the dictionary stack, but the return type is set to NSDictionary in `- (NSDictionary *)objectWithData:(NSData *)data`.

Comment: I get a warning "Incompatible pointer types initializing 'NSARRAY*' with an expression of type 'NSDictionay'

Comment: That is because your XMLReader-class says it is returning an NSDictionary, but it is not. You can either change the return-type in your XMLReader, or cast the return value to make the warning go away.